# Не происходит перенос чисел из стека в массив

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, стек

Имеется код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <conio.h>
void addElements(stack *&stack1);
int menu();
void input(int &a);
void searchMaxValue(stack *stack1);
using namespace std;
struct stack {
    int inf;
    stack *head, *next;
};
int main() {
    stack *stack1 = new stack;
    stack1->head = NULL;
    while (true) {
        switch (menu())
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter the element:" << endl;
            addElements(stack1);
            cout << "Element added" << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            searchMaxValue(stack1);
            break;
        case 0:
            cout << "Press Enter if you want to exit" << endl;
            if (_getch() == 13) {
                delete stack1->head;
                delete stack1->next;
                delete stack1;
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Choose 1-4 or 0" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
void addElements(stack *&stack1) {
    int inf;
    input(inf);
    stack *temp = new stack;
    temp->inf = inf;
    temp->next = stack1->head;
    stack1->head = temp;
}
int menu() {
    cout << "1 - add element" << endl;
    cout << "2 - show stack" << endl;
    cout << "3 - clear stack" << endl;
    cout << "4 - delete max element" << endl;
    cout << "0 - exit" << endl;
    int choise;
    input(choise);
    return choise;
}
void input(int &a) {
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> a;
        if (cin.good()) {
            break;
        }
        cout << "Wrong input" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
void searchMaxValue(stack *stack1) {
    stack *temp = stack1->head;
    int i = 0, n = 0;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
        n++;
    }
    int *arr = new int[n];
    while (temp != NULL) {
        arr[i] = temp->inf;
        temp = temp->next;
        i++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Задача - поиск и удаление максимального элемента стека, но еще не доделал. Решил реализовывать это следующим образом: заполнить стек, перенести все из стека в массив, удалить в массиве максимальный элемент и потом все назад в стек вернуть. Однако при переносе из стека в массив при любом содержимом стека на выходе получаю:

> -842150451
>   в каждой ячейке массива. Понимаю, что это происходит из-за того, что все элементы массива остаются пустыми, но не понимаю, из-за чего так.

Answer (score 2):

Я так и не понял, что у вас с массивом, но идея сама по себе сомнительна. С тем же успехом можно искать элементы непосредственно в списке, особенно если он отсортирован. Можно вообще хранить элементы в отсортированном массиве и не париться. Если всё же использовать списки, проще обрабатывать удаление и добавление, если есть указатели на начало и конец списка.

Я немного переделал ваш вариант, надеюсь вам станет понятнее, как работать со списками.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

struct stack {
    int value;
    stack *head, *tail;
};

stack* addElements(stack *oldTail, int value) {
    stack *newTail = new stack{ value, oldTail, nullptr };
    if(oldTail)
       oldTail->tail = newTail;
    return newTail;
}

stack* findMax(stack* head) {
    if(head == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    stack* ret = head;
    for(stack* tail = head->tail; tail != nullptr; tail = tail->tail){
        if(ret->value < tail->value)
          ret = tail;
    }
    return ret;
}

void remove(stack* node){
    if(node == nullptr)
      return;

    stack* head = node->head;
    stack* tail = node->tail;
    delete node;
    if(head)
      head->tail = tail;
    if(tail)
      tail->head = head;
}


void input(int &a) {
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> a;
        if (cin.good()) {
            break;
        }
        cout << "Wrong input" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}

int menu() {
    cout << "1 - add element" << endl;
    cout << "2 - show stack" << endl;
    cout << "3 - clear stack" << endl;
    cout << "4 - find max element" << endl;
    cout << "5 - remove max element" << endl;
    cout << "0 - exit" << endl;
    int choise;
    input(choise);
    return choise;
}

int main() {
    stack *stackHead = nullptr;
    stack *stackTail = nullptr;

    while (true) {
        switch (menu())
        {
        case 1:{
            cout << "Enter the element:" << endl;
            int value = 0;
            input(value);
            stackTail = addElements(stackTail, value);
            if(stackHead == nullptr)
              stackHead = stackTail;
            cout << "Element " << value << " added" << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            for(stack* head = stackHead; head != nullptr; head = head->tail){
                cout << head->value << " -> ";
            }
            cout << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            stack* node = findMax(stackHead);
            if(node)
                cout << node->value << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 5:{
            stack* node = findMax(stackHead);
            if(node){
                int value = node->value;
                if(node->head == nullptr)
                  stackHead = node->tail;
                if(node->tail == nullptr){
                    stackTail = node -> head;
                }
                remove(node);
                std::cout << "node " << value << " removed" << endl;
            }

            break;
        }
        case 0:{
            cout << "Press y if you want to exit" << endl;
            char ch;
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            if (cin.get(ch) && ch == 'y') {
                // TODO удалить стек в цикле
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout << "Choose 1-4 or 0" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: лучше хранить  в map

Comment: @ARHovsepyan , тогда уж лучше использовать `std::priority_queue`, построенный на `make_heap`, на крайней случай `boost::flat_set`, построенный на сортированном массиве. В случае больших объектов можно хранить в контейнере указатели на них. Обычные деревья (тем более std::map) преимуществ тут не дадут.

Comment: но map позволит не писать switch конструкцию, просто код нужен будет переделать и сделать более изящным